# Lamb Shift and virtual particles

Tags: particle-physics, hydrogen, virtual-particles, lamb-shift

Can someone explain about the Lamb Shift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lamb shift cannot be dealt with in classical (or semi-classical) terms. In QED it is known as a radiative correction and is mainly due to three effects, all involving [Loop Diagrams](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-loop_Feynman_diagram)

[image]

The lefthand picture portrays the describes random spontaneous production of electron-positron pairs close to the nucleus of the atom. This temporary pair product results in a reduction of the electric charge of the proton on the electron.

The second diagram is meant to convey  the fact that the ground state of the electromagnetic field is not zero, so  as the electron travels near the the 'vacuum fluctuations' in the electromagnetic field, it "zigzags" slightly, and this alters its energy as each zig or zag  results in a slight change of energy.

The third diagram refers to a very small adjustment to the electron's [Electron dipole moment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment).

Taken together, these effects comprise the reason for the Lamb shift.

This answer is basically a copy of David Griffith's explanation in his Particle Physics textbook, including the above illustration.

Answer (score 1):

Wiki says:
"
Interaction between vacuum energy fluctuations and the hydrogen electron in these different orbitals is the cause of the Lamb shift, as was shown subsequent to its discovery.
"
The EM field in which a photon is created also contains a small level of background energy (called the vacuum fluctuations) which can't be observed but are predicted by theory.   The orbitals interact with this field in different ways (due to their shape or symmetry), Lamb was able to measure this difference.